# Google Analytics: How to properly filter ga:1dayUsers and ga:30dayUsers

Tags: google-analytics

**Question**: What is the right way to filter active users based on the presence of an event?

I'm trying to report on a count of users that have performed a particular action (purchased an item) on my site.

The aim is to have a Daily Unique Buyer (akin to DAU or 1dayUsers) and Monthly Unique Buyer (akin MAU or 30dayUser) metric.

For the Daily Unique Buyer metric I have tried two separate approaches and I am getting different results for both.

Approach 1) Use ga:Users metric and apply filter ga:eventCategory=="Purchase"

Approach 2) Create custom Segment, Ensure that Advanced Filter condition is for Users (not Sessions) and set the same filter ga:eventCategory=="Purchase"

The first approach seems to yield the desired result when compared to the second.

Unfortunately, the first approach does not extend to computing the same metric for Monthly Unique Buyers.

Most post on StackOverflow suggest that creating a segment (approach 2) is the right way forward. This however, yields more users than events, which can't be correct.

Even more perplexing - Applying the segment in Audience -> Active Users interface yields a different result to programmatic app-script query below

```
const optArgs = {
  'dimensions': 'ga:date',
   'sort': '-ga:date','
    start-index': '1', 
   'max-results': 250,
   'segment: 'gaid::xxxx',
}
Analytics.Data.Ga.get(
  myViewId, startDate, endDate, 'ga:1dayUsers', optArgs
);
```

Answer (score 0):

update: For those that struggled with this. I don't claim to understand why, but I was able to get the correct number by querying the desired metrics 1dayUsers and 30dayUsers **one date at a time**.

Running the report over a date range failed. I checked this with the list of actual active users (under User Explorer in the interface) and both 1 day and 30 day metrics are correct.

Would love for someone to explain why this is needed.